# Can we find the line size in multiline text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox, multiline

I have multi-line text box in asp.net with 7 rows and with max size 700 bytes and Now, each row should take only 100 bytes if it exceeds it should move to next line until it reach the max size.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Yes, you can...

Comment: as far as I know the max size of a textbox is not specified in bytes. Anyway, yes it's possible. What specifically is giving you trouble in achieving your aim? What have you researched? What have you tried? This is not a free write-my-code or do-my-research service. We'll _help_ you, but we won't just give you a ready-made solution on a plate.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3e3EH/721/

Below code works :

```
<textarea id="foo" cols="50" var rows="7"></textarea>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var textArea = $('#foo');
    var maxRows = textArea.attr('rows');
    var maxChars = textArea.attr('cols');
    textArea.keypress(function(e){
        var text = textArea.val();
        var lines = text.split('\n');
        if (e.keyCode == 13){
            return lines.length < maxRows;
        }
        else{ //Should check for backspace/del/etc.
            var caret = textArea.get(0).selectionStart;
            console.log(caret);

            var line = 0;
            var charCount = 0;
            $.each(lines, function(i,e){
                charCount += e.length;
                if (caret <= charCount){
                    line = i;
                    return false;
                }
                //\n count for 1 char;
                charCount += 1;
            });

            var theLine = lines[line];
            return theLine.length < maxChars;
        }
    });

});
```